# "must have" for obligations

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

"Must (Probability)" has this structure: "must have PP". But can "Must (Obligation)" have that structure?

[Ok, now, must (Probability) can be used to express the high probability](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/modal-verbs-of-probability.html)

Ex: **She must be on the bus.** (I'm fairly sure this is a good guess)

& in the past: **She must have been on the bus yesterday.** (I'm fairly sure this is a good guess)

[But, must (obligation) can be used to express strong obligation](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/modal-verbs-of-obligation.html)

Ex: **She must study today**.

& in the past: **She had to study yesterday** (as in textbook)

My question is that:

Can "**Must (Obligation)**" have the structure "**must have PP**"?

So, is "**She had to study yesterday**" (as in textbook) the same as "**She must have studied yesterday**"?

Or, whenever we say "**She must have studied yesterday**", people will think "**must**" here refers to a Probability?

Comment: They'll think it refers to probability. The only way to use *must* to describe past obligation is with a "framing" construction, one that will sound somewhat dated and awkward in today's English. One example: "It was clear that he must study yesterday." Another: "Nothing would suffice then but that he must give his opinion on the matter."

Comment: In your second link, if you scroll all the way down, you'll see the answer to your question: "Remember 'must have done' is a modal verb of deduction or speculation, not obligation in the past. For example: Julie must have left. Her coat's not here."

Answer (score 1):

The example can mean both things, it very much depends on the context provided. Most of the time it will refer to probability and I would personally prefer not to use "must" for the other meaning but it can be done.